# SDN4 is always returning one relationship even though neo4j has multiple relationships

Tags: entity-framework, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4

I have two entities Person and Building. Both are related by two relationship entities "PERSON_HAS_ACCESS"(mutiple persons can access multiple buildings) and "PERSON_OWNS" (one Building can be owned by only one person, but a person can own multiple buildings). I am able to persist more than one relationship (2 to be specific) of each type and can see in the neo4j browser also. However, when I access the Person entity using the session API:

```
  session.loadAll(klazz, new Filter("uuid", uuid), 1).getAccessRelations.size()
```

always reurns back 1, not matter how many relationships it has.

I always get only one relationship back.

Here is my domain model. I added equals and hashcode, but issue still happens. Moreover, i tried having only one relationship, but again the issue is same. Its driving me crazy!!. Any help would be appreciated.

```
@NodeEntity
public class Building {
    @GraphId
    private Long id;

    private String uuid;

    @Relationship(type = "PERSON_OWNS", direction = Relationship.INCOMING)
    private OwnsBuilding ownsRelation;

    @Relationship(type = "PERSON_HAS_ACCESS", direction = Relationship.INCOMING)
    private Collection<CanAccess> accessRelations = new HashSet<CanAccess>();

    public Collection<CanAccess> getAccessRelations() {
    return accessRelations;
    }

    public Building setAccessRelations(Collection<CanAccess> accessRelations) {
    this.accessRelations = accessRelations;
    return this;
    }

    public String getUuid() {
    return uuid;
    }

    public Building setUuid(String uuid) {
    this.uuid = uuid;
    return this;
    }

    public OwnsBuilding getOwnsRelation() {
    return ownsRelation;
    }

    public Building setOwnsRelation(OwnsBuilding ownsRelation) {
    this.ownsRelation = ownsRelation;
    return this;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (obj == null || !(obj instanceof Building)) return false;
    if(id == null) return false;
    return obj == this || this.id.equals(((Building) obj).id);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
    return id != null ? id.hashCode() : super.hashCode();
    }
}


@NodeEntity
public class Person {

    private String uuid;

    @GraphId
    private Long id;

    @Relationship(type = "PERSON_HAS_ACCESS", direction = Relationship.OUTGOING)
    private Collection<CanAccess> accessRelations = new HashSet<CanAccess>();

    @Relationship(type = "PERSON_OWNS", direction = Relationship.OUTGOING)
    private Collection<OwnsBuilding> ownsRelations = new HashSet<OwnsBuilding>();

    public Collection<CanAccess> getAccessRelations() {
    return accessRelations;
    }

    public Person setAccessRelations(Collection<CanAccess> accessRelations) {
    this.accessRelations = accessRelations;
    return this;
    }

    public String getUuid() {
    return uuid;
    }

    public Person setUuid(String uuid) {
    this.uuid = uuid;
    return this;
    }

    public Collection<OwnsBuilding> getOwnsRelations() {
    return ownsRelations;
    }

    public Person setOwnsRelations(Collection<OwnsBuilding> ownsRelations) {
    this.ownsRelations = ownsRelations;
    return this;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (obj == null || !(obj instanceof Person)) return false;
    if (id == null) return false;
    return obj == this || this.id.equals(((Person) obj).id);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
    return id != null ? id.hashCode() : super.hashCode();
    }
}


@RelationshipEntity(type = "PERSON_HAS_ACCESS")
public class CanAccess {
    @GraphId
    private Long id;

    @StartNode
    private Person person;

    public CanAccess(){}

    public CanAccess(Person person, Building building) {
    this.person = person;
    this.building = building;
    }

    @EndNode
    private Building building;

    public Person getPerson() {
    return person;
    }

    public CanAccess setPerson(Person person) {
    this.person = person;
    return this;
    }

    public Building getBuilding() {
    return building;
    }

    public CanAccess setBuilding(Building building) {
    this.building = building;
    return this;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (obj == null || !(obj instanceof CanAccess)) return false;
    if (id == null) return false;
    return obj == this || this.id.equals(((CanAccess) obj).id);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
    return id != null ? id.hashCode() : super.hashCode();
    }
}


@RelationshipEntity(type = "PERSON_OWNS")
public class OwnsBuilding {
    @GraphId
    private Long id;

    public OwnsBuilding() {
    }

    public OwnsBuilding(Person owner, Building building) {
    this.owner = owner;
    this.building = building;
    }

    @StartNode

    private Person owner;

    @EndNode
    private Building building;

    public Person getOwner() {
    return owner;
    }

    public OwnsBuilding setOwner(Person owner) {
    this.owner = owner;
    return this;
    }

    public Building getBuilding() {
    return building;
    }

    public OwnsBuilding setBuilding(Building building) {
    this.building = building;
    return this;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (obj == null || !(obj instanceof OwnsBuilding)) return false;
    if (id == null) return false;
    return obj == this || this.id.equals(((OwnsBuilding) obj).id);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
    return id != null ? id.hashCode() : super.hashCode();
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you not have any properties in the relationship entities?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please change your `Collection` to a `Set` -

```
 @Relationship(type = "PERSON_HAS_ACCESS", direction = Relationship.INCOMING)
 private Collection<CanAccess> accessRelations = new HashSet<CanAccess>();
```

to

```
 @Relationship(type = "PERSON_HAS_ACCESS", direction = Relationship.INCOMING)
 private Set<CanAccess> accessRelations = new HashSet<CanAccess>();
```

The OGM can create arrays or `Set`,`List`,`Vector`.

Also, though unrelated to the issue, please make sure that when your relationship direction is `INCOMING`, you explicitly annotate any properties/accessors/mutators.
In your case:

```
@Relationship(type = "PERSON_HAS_ACCESS", direction = Relationship.INCOMING)
private Set<CanAccess> accessRelations = new HashSet<CanAccess>();

@Relationship(type = "PERSON_HAS_ACCESS", direction = Relationship.INCOMING)
public Set<CanAccess> getAccessRelations() {...}

@Relationship(type = "PERSON_HAS_ACCESS", direction = Relationship.INCOMING)
public Building setAccessRelations(Set<CanAccess> accessRelations) {...}
```

Another is to [make sure your object model is navigable](http://graphaware.com/neo4j/2015/09/03/sdn-4-object-model.html) especially in the case of relationship entities. When you create the relationship entity, remember to set it on participating nodes, e.g

```
public CanAccess(Person person, Building building) {
    this.person = person;
    this.building = building;
    this.person.getAccessRelations().add(this);
    this.building.getAccessRelations().add(this);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Luanne, this seems to be working. I will do some more testing. Could you please explain the reason for changing the declaration to Set. Also does this apply to all the relationships  that I can have in my domain model?

Comment: It is because the OGM will only create arrays or Sets or Lists or Vectors of relationships. Yes, applies to any collection of relationships in your domain model

Comment: one more doubt i have, does it make sense to have equals and hashcode methods to be overridden for the relationship entities?

Comment: The OGM used by SDN does not rely on these, so you should implement whatever makes sense for your application. Each relationship entity is a different relationship in the underlying graph (with properties). If you have no properties on it, then you don't need a relationship entity, just a plain @Relationship